# How to do Mongodb Backup with node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, database-backups

I am wirting a mongodb auto backup code but i am stuck in some error: 'mongodump' is not recognized as an internal or external command.
can anyone help me out?

or is there another way to get auto backup with mongodb

```
exports.dbAutoBackUp = () => {

        let cmd =
        'mongodump --host ' +
        dbOptions.host +
        ' --port ' +
        dbOptions.port +
        ' --db ' +
        dbOptions.database +
        ' --username ' +
        dbOptions.user +
        ' --password ' +
        dbOptions.pass +
        ' --out ' +
        newBackupPath;

        exec(cmd, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
            console.log("Error : "+error)
            console.log("Error 1: "+stdout)
            console.log("Error 2: "+stderr)
        if (this.empty(error)) {
            // check for remove old backup after keeping # of days given in configuration.
            if (dbOptions.removeOldBackup == true) {
            if (fs.existsSync(oldBackupPath)) {
                exec('rm -rf ' + oldBackupPath, err => {
                    console.log(err);
                });
            }
            }
        }
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: What is your current MongoDB setup btw ? What version is installed and are you sure you have configured your PATH correctly to make `mongodump` util available globally on your system ?

Comment: Did you look at any node module out there?

Answer (score 0):

The error is probably because you are not in the directory where you have mongodb executable. 
There are two ways to do it.

1. change your directory to mongodb's installation path
2. Add the mongodb executable to your environment variables

Path should be something like

`{installation_directory}:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\{version}\bin`

For example
`C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.2\bin`

Comment: can you explain more, like how to this because my mongo db database is running on docker contaienr and this code is running on another container,

Comment: sorry you didn't mention about docker. take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46438659/correct-syntax-to-do-mongodump-of-mongodb-docker-instance)